# How to test email in functional test (Symfony2)

Tags: symfony, functional-testing, swiftmailer

I'm trying to test email in functional test...

My source code is the same as the [example of the cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/testing.html),

the controller :

```
public function sendEmailAction($name)
{
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('Hello Email')
        ->setFrom('send@example.com')
        ->setTo('recipient@example.com')
        ->setBody('You should see me from the profiler!')
    ;

    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

    return $this->render(...);
}
```

And the test :

```
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/Tests/Controller/MailControllerTest.php
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class MailControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testMailIsSentAndContentIsOk()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        // Enable the profiler for the next request (it does nothing if the profiler is not available)
        $client->enableProfiler();

        $crawler = $client->request('POST', '/path/to/above/action');

        $mailCollector = $client->getProfile()->getCollector('swiftmailer');

        // Check that an e-mail was sent
        $this->assertEquals(1, $mailCollector->getMessageCount());

        $collectedMessages = $mailCollector->getMessages();
        $message = $collectedMessages[0];

        // Asserting e-mail data
        $this->assertInstanceOf('Swift_Message', $message);
        $this->assertEquals('Hello Email', $message->getSubject());
        $this->assertEquals('send@example.com', key($message->getFrom()));
        $this->assertEquals('recipient@example.com', key($message->getTo()));
        $this->assertEquals(
            'You should see me from the profiler!',
            $message->getBody()
        );
    }
}
```

however I got this error :

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getCollector() on a
>   non-object

The problem comes from this line :

```
$mailCollector = $client->getProfile()->getCollector('swiftmailer');
```

any idea ?

Comment: was my answer helpful? if yes please upvote/accept otherwise please comment if something's missing or not working :-)

Comment: I am not able to check for the while... but don't worry, I keep your solution and will try it out next week ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exception is being thrown because `getProfile()` returns false if the profiler is not enabled. see [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Client.php#L66).

```
public function getProfile()
{
    if (!$this->kernel->getContainer()->has('profiler')) {
        return false;
    }

    return $this->kernel->getContainer()->get('profiler')->loadProfileFromResponse($this->response);
}
```

Furthermore `enableProfiler()`only enables the profiler if it is registered with the service-container aka enabled. see [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Client.php#L80).

```
public function enableProfiler()
{
    if ($this->kernel->getContainer()->has('profiler')) {
        $this->profiler = true;
    }
}
```

Now you have to make sure  the profiler is enabled in the test environment. ( should normally be the [default setting](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#profiler) )

**config_test.yml**

```
framework:
   profiler:
       enabled: true
```

You could add something like this to your test:

```
$this->assertEquals($this->kernel->getContainer()->has('profiler'), true);
```

Comment: Hi @nifr, it is really helpful for me. thnx

Comment: Note for readers: you have to disable redirects if you want to use the profiler after having submitted a form. `$client->followRedirects(false);        $client->enableProfiler(); $client->submit($form); /* use profiler */ if ($profile = $client->getProfile()) {…} /* open target page */ $crawler = $client->request('GET', $client->getResponse()->headers->get('location'));`