# Using PHPMailer without gmail account

Tags: php, symfony, phpmailer

I wanted to test locally sending mails via PHPMailer (Symfony3 framework), but on the internet i see only configurations for gmail accounts. Is it possible to not configure any external server to send mails for testing locally?

Comment: Not what you asked for but you should be aware of the email development tools that Symfony provides: http://symfony.com/doc/current/email/dev_environment.html

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. If you want to **actually send** the email then you need an SMTP server (it could be gmail or you could install one locally). If you want to create a test case and check if the email is sent - then checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17279072/393805) question for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up your local server to handle smtp requests, or you can use a service like Mailtrap: https://mailtrap.io/

From their website: "Mailtrap is a fake SMTP server for development teams to test, view and share emails sent from the development and staging environments without spamming real customers."

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but I would not recommend it. You can look up the mx for a domain and send directly to it using PHPMailer without any particular problems, however, PHPMailer is not an MTA, so you would be much better off using a local mail server to accept your message and deliver it asynchronously. The actual code is much the same as for Gmail, you just need to do the mx lookup first, set that as the `Host` and send to it without authentication on port 25.